# SQL Server Encryption not supported on the client error

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, windows-server-2008-r2

I've tried to deploy a php codeigniter website with a sql server but it keep showing **database error occured page** , so i'm writing a php script to test the connection and then got this error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Encryption not supported on
> the client.

Here's my setup

1. SQL Server 2008
2. Windows server 2008 R2 SP1
3. SQL Native Client  10
4. ODBC 17.5
5. PHP 7.4

I've done this on another machine with windows 10, it's run smoothly

some says it's need a sql native client version 11, so i've installed it and remove the old one , and the server won't run. How to update your sql native client properly ?

Comment: SQL Native Client 10 and ODBC Driver for SQL Server are two completely different things.  No one uses SNAC anymore.  What errors are logged on SQL Server?

Comment: What version of SQL Server is involved: "SELECT @@VERSION"